# SQL Server self-update TRUNCATE value using ISNULL

Tags: sql-server, truncate, isnull

I do not know if this is a bug.

I found that when this code is run the value in column `MyComments` is truncated to the first letter. It seems to be related to the declaration of variable `@MYComments`, cause after I changed the declaration to `VARCHAR(MAX)` it worked, but what seems to be weird for me is that if no value is set to variable `@MYComments` function `ISNULL(@MYComments, MYComments)` invocation should returns the current value.

```
DECLARE @MYComments AS VARCHAR

UPDATE [dbo].[TestIssue] 
SET MYComments = ISNULL(@MYComments,MYComments)
```

I was able to reproduce this using this script.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
SET ARITHABORT ON
SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF
SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON
COMMIT
BEGIN TRANSACTION
GO
CREATE TABLE dbo.TestIssue
    (
    id int NOT NULL,
    MYComments varchar(MAX) NOT NULL
    )  ON [PRIMARY]
     TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.TestIssue SET (LOCK_ESCALATION = TABLE)
GO
COMMIT
select Has_Perms_By_Name(N'dbo.TestIssue', 'Object', 'ALTER') as ALT_Per, Has_Perms_By_Name(N'dbo.TestIssue', 'Object', 'VIEW DEFINITION') as View_def_Per, Has_Perms_By_Name(N'dbo.TestIssue', 'Object', 'CONTROL') as Contr_Per 

INSERT INTO [dbo].[TestIssue]
           ([id]
           ,[MYComments])
     VALUES
           (1
           ,'MY COMMENT 1')
GO

SELECT * FROM [dbo].[TestIssue]

DECLARE @MYComments AS VARCHAR

UPDATE [dbo].[TestIssue] 
SET MYComments = ISNULL(@MYComments,MYComments)

SELECT * FROM [dbo].[TestIssue]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is with declararion:

```
Declare @Mycomments VARCHAR
```

This declaration means that is 1 char long, so return of ISNULL should be also 1 char long. Change declarstion to VARCHAR(MAX). It solve your problem.

Comment: Or change it to `VARCHAR(n)` where `n` is a suitable value between 1 and 8000 - doesn't have to be `(MAX)` (2 **billion** characters!) all the time! You just have to explicitly **define a length** ....

Comment: Assuming that you know the `n` ;)